# Minimum of a function $f(x,y)=\frac{(1+2y)(1+\frac{x}{2})}{(1+y)(1+x)+x}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

what is the minimum of a function 
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\frac{(1+2y)(1+\frac{x}{2})}{(1+y)(1+x)+x}\\
\text {s.t. }& 1 \le y \le x \le y(1+y) 
\end{align}

I asked Wolfram and Alfa and it says that the minimum is $f(x,y)=0.8565$.
I found the derivative with respect to both x and y:
\begin{align}
\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}&=\frac{4\, x + 3\, y + 4\, x\, y + 2\, x^2\, y + 4\, x^2 + 1}{2\, {\left(2\, x + y + x\, y + 1\right)}^2}\\
\frac{df(x,y)}{dy}&=- \frac{\left(2\, x + 1\right)\, \left(\frac{x}{2} + 1\right)\, \left(x + 1\right)}{{\left(x + \left(x + 1\right)\, \left(y + 1\right)\right)}^2}
\end{align}

Should I set up Lagrangian next or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{(\frac{1}{2}+y)x+(y+1)+1}{(2+y)x+(y+1)}=1+\dfrac{1-\frac{3}{2}x}{(2+y)x+(y+1)}$

so it is a mono decreasing function for $x \implies f_{min}=f(y(y+1),y)=f_1(y)$

now use same method to check if $f_1(y)$ is mono decreasing function or not.thenthe answer is easy to get.

Comment: Could you show me how you factor you function to the form $f(x,y)=\frac{(0.5+y)x+(y+1)+1}{(2+y)x+(y+1)}$???

Comment: $(\frac{1}{2}+y)x+(y+1)+1=(2+y)x-\frac{3}{2}x+(y+1)+1$

Answer (score 0):

i think first you should obtain grad of f then grad f=0 if you find x,y that 
Applies to domain its minimum else using lagrangian method.

Comment: Yes. I tried. Very messy expression.

Comment: sorry for my bad english :D